# Probability of an event happening in a given istant

Tags: time-series, distributions, survival, recurrent-events

**Simplified context**: I'm watching traffic over a computer network. I consider "connection" as an *event*, *which* obviously *can repeat many times during a period of time*. I observe my network for 24 hours: during work hours there will be a lot of event repetition, somewhat fewer during the rest of the day and almost none at night.
Now what I want to do is, considering my 24-hour observation as representative, calculate the *probability of event happening at a given time* the next day.
Can you help me? I'm rusty about distributions, but I'm sure that this isn't an unseen problem. Even a "you are probably looking for x" answer would be great :D 
Thank you all in advance.

**Edit for clarity:**
My objective is this: after the initial 24-hour observation I want to observe the traffic for another 24-hour and when I observe an event I want to take the time it happened and calculate how likely it was to happen. What I'm trying to do is understanding (infering?) if a given time is an "unusual" one for the event to be observed.

Comment: The answer is zero. (This follows directly from the axioms of probability.)  Are you perhaps looking for a probability *density?* That would be a probability per unit of time.

Comment: @whuber edited for clarity. I apologize if I fall short on the correct lingo

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis

Comment: @LBogaardt so your suggestion is to consider the time between two repetition instead of the time of the event?

Comment: That depends on what your mechanism is. It's still a bit unclear to me. Statistics cannot be used on a N=1 sample, so there would need to be many events at many times before you can extract a pattern. Try to read about survival analysis and see if you can find a model which comes close to your own mechanism.

Comment: My statistic should be based on the first 24-hour observation during which the event will repeat N~=2 million times. What I'm trying to do is: "during my first observation there is no event from 4am to 6am, few events from 6am to 8am and millions of events from 8am to 10am. So if during my second observation there is an event at 5:26am it should be considered 'unlikely', while one at 9:13am should be considered 'likely'." This, on a obviously more formal basis and with a higher time resolution, is what I'm trying to achieve.